# shared memory not updating

Tags: c, exec, mmap

So I've been trying to learn a little more about shared memory. I am creating a shared memory structure in my master and forking off children. Each child is then creating a new process using execv. When I try to change the value of shared memory from the new process the parent does not see that change. Also I was expecting the parent to interleave execution with child. For Example

```
Child 1 exec 
parent 
child 2 exec 
parent 
child 3 exec
parent
```

But Instead I get

```
child 1 exec 
child 2 exec 
child 3 exec 
parent
parent
parent
```

this is my code

**simulate.c**

```
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <dirent.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <getopt.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
# include <ctype.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <signal.h>
# include <sys/mman.h>
# include <sys/time.h>
# include <stdint.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <sys/shm.h>
struct sharedregion{
    volatile int seconds;
    volatile int sharedmsg;
};
struct sharedregion *mystruct;
void spawnchild()
{
    int fd = shm_open("sharedmemory", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXU);
    if (fd == -1)
        perror("Error in opening");
    if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct sharedregion)) == -1)
        perror("Unable to truncate");
    mystruct = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct sharedregion),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED| MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);
    if (mystruct == MAP_FAILED)
        perror("mapping failed");
    mystruct->seconds=0;
    mystruct->sharedmsg=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        pid_t pID = fork();

        if (pID == 0)
        {
            static char *args[]={"./child",NULL};

            execv(args[0], args);
            perror("failed to execv");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        }
        else if (pID < 0)            // failed to fork
        {
            perror(" Failed to fork:");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if(pID>0)
        {

            printf("\nfrom parent= %d",mystruct->sharedmsg);
            mystruct->seconds=mystruct->seconds+1;
            if(mystruct->seconds==1000000000)
            {
                mystruct->seconds=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    spawnchild();
}
```

**child.c**

```
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <dirent.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <getopt.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
# include <ctype.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <signal.h>
# include <sys/mman.h>
# include <sys/time.h>
# include <stdint.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <sys/shm.h>
struct sharedregion{
    volatile int seconds;
        volatile int sharedmsg;
};
struct sharedregion *mystruct;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int memFd = shm_open("sharedmemory", O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXU);
    if (memFd == -1)
    {
        perror("Can't open file");
        return 1;
    }

    mystruct = mmap(NULL, sizeof (struct sharedregion), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED| MAP_ANONYMOUS, memFd, 0);

    printf("\nhello from exec");
    mystruct->sharedmsg=8;
    printf("buffer %d",mystruct->sharedmsg);

    return 0;
}
```

**My output**

```
hello from execbuffer 8
hello from execbuffer 8
hello from execbuffer 8
hello from execbuffer 8
hello from execbuffer 8
from parent= 0
from parent= 0
from parent= 0
from parent= 0
from parent= 0
```

Comment: The parent and children run concurrently, you have nothing that's synchronizing them.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the parent is showing a different value in `mystruct->sharedmsg` than the children.

Comment: It could be that the parent reads the shared memory before the child updates it. What happens if you add a `wait` call to the parent before it reads the shared memory?

Comment: @IanAbbott Isn't `volatile` supposed to prevent that?

Comment: You should put `\n` at the *end* of your `printf` strings. `stdout` is line-buffered, so you should print a newline immediately after the message to ensure that it's printed at the time you expect.

Comment: Tried wait, still the same output.

Comment: @Barmar `volatile` isn't a synchronization mechanism. (At least, not on its own.)

Comment: @IanAbbott That's true, but we can still assume that the reads are happening in the same order that the output is produced, because a volatile variable is being passed to `printf()`.

Comment: @Barmar That may depend on whether the output is line buffered or fully buffered. There is something weird happening with the buffering, and putting the `\n` at the beginning of the line instead of the end would make it a bit weird anyway.

Comment: That's why I recommended earlier that he fix the newline.

Comment: Is `stdout` going to the terminal or a file? That changes how the buffering is done.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the flag MAP_ANONYMOUS

according to the manual:

> MAP_ANONYMOUS
>                 [...] The fd argument is ignored;

thus it ignores your shared memory

Comment: That said, @Barmar is rigth to stress that synchronization is still necessary to make sure there are memory barrieres that make sure each process do not read partial data. You may do that with IPC semaphores (see man sem_init, sem_open and friends)

Comment: Made the change still gives the same output

Comment: on both sides ?

Comment: getting the same output is expected, in you test you don't try to read something written by the other process... try setting some values from the father at startup, and see it in the child. I you need to have "interleaved" interactions, you need synchronization between processes

Comment: Doesn't `printf("\nfrom parent= %d",mystruct->sharedmsg);` try to read something written by the child?

Comment: the line before you do `mystruct->sharedmsg=8;`, thus whatever was written by father, you overwrite it...